# Fresh install flutter in ubuntu 18.04 wont run my first app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-test

I tried to create my first app using `flutter create newapp`

but it wont run i always get an error

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to 
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s 
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: flutter doctor all good

Answer (score 0):

I just wipe all the cache in .gradle/cache and it works